# When I use the DropDownListFor in view mode, [Required(ErrorMessage = "")] not worked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I found that if I use the DropDownListFor in view mode, the [Required(ErrorMessage = "")] of the variable will not work in the form.

[image: when the StaffId is Null, there returns an error]

Model :

```
    [Key]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pls input id")]
    public int StaffId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("UserType")]
    public int UserTypeId { get; set; }
```

Controller :

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

        List<SelectListItem> listItem = new List<SelectListItem>();
        listItem.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "A", Value = "1" });
        listItem.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "B", Value = "2" });
        listItem.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "C", Value = "3" });
        ViewData["List"] = new SelectList(listItem, "Value", "Text", "");

        return View();
    }
```

View :

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StaffId, "StaffId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StaffId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" },  })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StaffId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserTypeId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserTypeId, ViewData["List"] as SelectList, "請選擇", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserTypeId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserTypeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

If the StaffId is null, then it will return error in the Microsoft Visual Studio,

[image: Error Msg]

Comment: What is your actual question? Your screen shot message is not in English, but best guess is that your getting an error when you submit and in the post method you return the view - you have not shown the relevant code, but you need to repopulate the value of `ViewData["List"]` before you return the view otherwise its `null` and an exception will be thrown

Comment: And just use `ViewData["List"] = listItem;` - creating a 2nd identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from the first one is pointless extra overhead.

Comment: Seems that you want to passing a model class (e.g. `[ModelClassName]`) which contains `UserTypeId` property (i.e. `@model [ModelClassName]`), but the controller doesn't use `return View([ModelClassName])`, instead a `SelectList` being passed into `ViewData` which throwing IOE since an invalid cast has occurred.

Comment: If you are using `ViewData["List"] = listItem` You have to update your view code to cast it to `List<SelectListItem>`.  (I would prefer that though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If the StaffId is null.....

With the code you shown, `StaffId` property of your view model (Assuming you are using an object of that as the parameter of your action method) will never be null because it is not nullable. If user did not select anything other than your defaul label, it will be `0` (default int value).

Now regarding the errror, this usually happens when you post your form and in the httppost action method you are returning the same view without reloading the relevant collection needed to populate the dropdown in ViewData. So make sure you reload the collection before returning to the view.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(YourViewModel model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
       // to do :Save and Redirect ( PRG pattern)
  }
  // Let's reload the collection needed to render the dropdown
  var listItem = new List<SelectListItem>(){
    new SelectListItem { Text = "A", Value = "1" },
    new SelectListItem { Text = "B", Value = "2" }
  };
  ViewData["List"] = new SelectList(listItem, "Value", "Text", "");
  return View(model);
}
```